# The server requires a username and password fileupload control and System.IO

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, file-upload, .net

I'm given an ftp username/password to update a website via the ftp server. The project calls for the fileupload control and for me to delete a file on the server. A file should be uploaded onto the server with fileupload and a file should be deleted with the file.delete method. Instead, it says `The server randdomain.com:80 requires a username and password`.

It works fine in Visual Studio on my computer. How do I get it to simply upload the file? The area of the site with the fileupload has forms authentication. The ftp password and forms authentication password both do not work.

How do I get it to upload the file?

Comment: I think you misunderstand me. I have to add new files to the website randdomain.com, so i do. 1 of those files has a fileupload and file.delete, and i get that error when those r run. the site has forms authentication. i do the action via the website. the fileupload and file.delete works on my computer, but not on the website.

Comment: Ok, sorry I misunderstanding, still do not understand.

Comment: thats ok. let me explain again. i am given a website (randdomain.com) and a ftp login and password. i put new pages in randdomain.com via windows explorer + ftp to make the website run better. the website has forms authentication. one of the added pages has a fileupload control and uses the file.delete method. however, when that is called, it gives that error.